Getting Exception 'java.util.ConcurrentModificationException using ConcurrentLinkedQueue
I have a loop that I want to run in parallel to create a Queue that will contain a few thousands of objects.
The queue is being created from a List running parallelStream() and I would like to add elements to the final queue.
I have tried queue.add and queue.offer and both produces the exception java.util.ConcurrentModificationException.
How can I add elements to a ConcurrentLinkedQueue in parallel?
The code is very similar to this
 List<MyType> sourceList = new List<MyType>(); 
 // sourceList has about 1000 entries

 Queue<MyType> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
 
 
sourceList.parallelStream().forEach( itemList -> { 
    MyType myObject = new MyType;  
    myObject.setProperty(itemList.getWantedProperty);

    // Using queue.add or queue.offer produces the same error
    queue.offer(myObject) 
    queue.add(myObject) 
});


Your example code doesn't compile. Also please add the full stack trace of the exception to your question.

To avoid ConcurrentModificationException when using ConcurrentLinkedQueue, ensure that you are not modifying the queue while iterating over it. Instead of removing elements during iteration, consider using methods like poll() in a loop, which is safe for concurrent modifications:
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
String element;
while ((element = queue.poll()) != null) {
    // Process element
}

This way, the queue is safely modified without causing exceptions.

My case is the opposite. I am addind elements to the queue not removing.
The goal is to process the List in parallel and compose the Queue allowing concurrent additions to the queue for performance.

@Neliosam: use an Iterator<MyType>

This would make sense to remove items from the collection but I need to add elements.
The issue occurs when I do queue.offer() or queue.add()..

@Neliosam: then create and post a [mre] (MRE) program, code that we can run, that demonstrates the problem for us. Add this new program as an edit to your original post. Please read the link and ask if anything is confusing about the link or about creating your own MRE.
